"Uwfmgr Filter Reset-Settings" is no longer supported. Is there an alternative?
As of April 2024, the docs about UWFMGR tool contains the following statement for the "Filter Reset-Settings" command:

Restores UWF settings to the original state. If you added UWF to your
image by using Turn Windows features on or off or by using DISM, the
original state is the state of UWF settings when UWF was first
enabled. If you added UWF to your image by using SMI settings in an
unattend file, the original state is the state of UWF settings when
Windows was installed on the device. Starting in Windows 10, this
command is no longer supported.

If the command is no more supported, is there another way to restore the UWF settings to the original state?
EDIT: Operative System is Windows 10 IoT Enterprise 21H2, Build 19044.4291

Isn't UWF_Filter.ResetSettings an alternative to this command?

That article hasn't been updated since July 2023. In other words, that particular note isn't actually new and is likely in the legacy documentation, too.

Original documentation from 2018 at the same statement

@harrymc also that command returns "Not Supported" when called from Powershell

According to the documentation this was supposed to be the replacement. Seems like this replacement was documented but never implemented. I think you will be able to continue with Reset-Settings for quite some time yet.
